Proof relies on the operator being a contraction...what is it in the statement of the lemma implies that the operator is a contraction?
I am trying to understand the following.
Lemma:
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, let $\Phi = \{E_a\}$ be a linear map $B(H) \to B(H)$ where $\Phi(X) = \sum_a E_aXE_a^*$ for all $X \in B(H)$ that is completely positive and unital, and let $X$ be an operator on $H$ such that
$$0 \leq X \leq \Phi(X).$$
Then the eigenspace $\ker(X - \|X\|I)$ is $E_a^*$-invariant for all $a$.
Proof:
WLOG let $\|X\| = 1$ and take $\xi \in \ker(X - \|X\|I)$ arbitrary.
$$\begin{aligned} \|\xi\|^2 &= \langle X\xi, \xi\rangle\\
&\leq \sum_a \langle E_aXE_a^*\xi, \xi\rangle\\
&= \sum_a \langle XE_a^*\xi, E_a^*\xi\rangle\\
&\leq \sum_a \langle E_a^*\xi, E_a^*\xi\rangle\\
&= \|\xi\|^2\end{aligned}.$$
Since $X$ is a positive contraction, we have $E_a^*\xi \in \ker(X - \|X\|I)$.

A contraction is an operator whose norm is $\leq 1$.
We took $\|X\| = 1$, so $X$ is certainly a contraction.
It is this fact that gives the second inequality above?
So if $X$ is a contraction and $A$ is any positive operator, then $XA \leq A$?
But we took $\|X\| = 1$ WLOG, so there must be something in the statement of the lemma that indicates that $X$ is a contraction.
So...a positive operator that is bounded by the action of a completely positive unital map on that operator is a contraction?
Is this accurate, is there a nicer way to say it, and could I have a hint in the direction of a proof?


It is this fact that gives the second inequality above?

Yes.

So if $X$ is a contraction and $A$ is any positive operator, then $XA \leq A$?

No. This doesn’t make sense, $XA$ may not even be self-adjoint. The fact used in the second inequality is that if $X$ is a positive contraction, then $X \leq I$, so $\langle X \eta, \eta \rangle \leq \langle \eta, \eta \rangle$ for all $\eta$.

So...a positive operator that is bounded by the action of a completely positive unital map on that operator is a contraction?

No, of course not. The property $0 \leq X \leq \Phi(X)$ is preserved if you multiply $X$ by any positive scalar $C > 0$. Even if $X$ is a contraction, it is certainly not the case that $CX$ is a contraction for all $C > 0$ - that would only happen if $X = 0$. By the way, this is also why we can assume WLOG $\|X\| = 1$. Whatever your original $X$ is, you can just change it to $X’ = \frac{X}{\|X\|}$. The eigenspace is the same: $\text{ker}(X - \|X\| I) = \text{ker}(X’ - \|X’\| I)$. We still have $0 \leq X’ \leq \Phi(X’)$. And we now have $\|X’\| = 1$.

To clear up any confusion, let me note here that the proof could have been done without assuming $\|X\| = 1$. The author probably only assumed that for notational simplicity. Indeed, the following is the altered proof without assuming $\|X\| = 1$:
Take $\xi \in \ker(X - \|X\|I)$ arbitrary. Then $X\xi = \|X\|\xi$, so we have,
$$\begin{split}
\|X\|\|\xi\|^2 &= \langle X\xi, \xi\rangle\\
&\leq \sum_a \langle E_aXE_a^*\xi, \xi\rangle\\
&= \sum_a \langle XE_a^*\xi, E_a^*\xi\rangle\\
&\leq \|X\|\sum_a \langle E_a^*\xi, E_a^*\xi\rangle\\
&= \|X\|\|\xi\|^2
\end{split}$$
Where in the second inequality we used $X \leq \|X\|I$. But this means, for all $a$, we have $\langle XE_a^*\xi, E_a^*\xi\rangle = \|X\| \langle E_a^*\xi, E_a^*\xi\rangle$. By spectral theorem, this can only happen if $XE_a^*\xi = \|X\|E_a^*\xi$, i.e., $E_a^*\xi \in \ker(X - \|X\| I)$.

You don't really need the spectral theorem in this situation. The equality $$\langle XE_a^\xi, E_a^\xi\rangle = |X| \langle E_a^\xi, E_a^\xi\rangle$$ can be written directly as $$|,(|X|-X)^{1/2}E_a^*\xi|^2=0.$$
